# NPM doesn't support PnP

Tags: npm, create-react-app, pnpm

I was trying use **pnpm** with create-react-app **v2** as follows

```
npx create-react-app my-app --use-pnp
```

But it gives me following warning

```
NPM doesn't support PnP.
Falling back to the regular installs.
```

What should I do in order to use pnpm with create-react-app?

I already have pnpm installed globally using npm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pnp is a Yarn feature, you need the latest version of yarn installed on your system to use it (at least Yarn 1.12).

Comment: Thanks Jed, I was so happy that I could get rid of node_modules, so now I have to use Yarn for that.

Comment: This works for me too, BUT what does "--use-pnp" mean? and, how does it work? it's not documented

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα There's more info in this RFC https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/pull/101 and the pnp whitepaper here https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/files/2378943/Plugnplay.pdf

Comment: Thanks Jed for the info, in short, "--use-pnp" is experimental. One request: under this same scenery, how do you enable your React app for working with ESLint and AirBnB? May you use Asciinema for this demo please?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
yarn create react-app project-name --use-pnp
```

And make sure `yarn -v` is >= 1.12

Comment: just in case "with-pnp" is the project name.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated to make it more clear